# Memory doesn't release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendfile, x-sendfile

I have a function that create a backup of the app and download it in a zip file, with the datas in the databases, images, files, etc. For this i create a big temp file (using the Tempfile class) that send to browser with send_data, but when i delete it after send_data the download failed and its memory is not released.

```
send_file(zip_data.path, type: 'application/zip', filename: "#{model_name}.zip")

zip_data.unlink
```

Service class: http://pastebin.com/MskjP8d7

Controller method: http://pastebin.com/CV9Wr27h

Answer (score 0):

It happens because by the time the `unlink` method is executed, the request hasn't been completely served yet and the server hasn't actually sent the file. `send_file` is actually handled by the web server.

You could either drop the `unlink` call. [Ruby garbage collector will clean up Tempfiles once they are out of scope](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#class-Tempfile-label-Explicit+close). Or, replace `send_file` with `send_data` and manually send the binary contents of your Zip file from within the controller.